# Whitelisting in Cordova (iOS application) build using MAF in JDeveloper

Tags: ios, cordova, jdeveloper, xcode7.3, oracle-maf

I need to deploy my application using **Xcode simulator** which need to contact a server. I need to **whitelist** it so as to allow its access in the application.

Since I am woking with **MAF 2.3.1**, which no longer supports Remote URL Whitelisting. So please help me whitelisting the remote url at which the server is deployed for the application to work.

Answer (score 0):

In your index.html file add

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' example.com">
```

or in Your config.xml file set

```
<access origin="http://google.com" />
```

Comment: can you please tell me where is this config file located?

Comment: AppName/platforms/ios/appname/config.xml  or it available in appname/config.xml. once you change anything in config.xml use this command from your terminal "cordova prepare"